# How do you comment out lines in AWS CLI config and credentials files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

For AWS CLI configuration and credentials files how do you comment out lines in these files - I checked the documentation here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-config-files but found nothing.

e.g.

~/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYY

[qa]
aws_access_key_id = AAAAAAAAA
aws_secret_access_key = BBBBBB
```

~/.aws/config

```
[default]
region = us-east-1

[profile qa]
region = us-west-2

[profile staging]
region = us-east-2
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can comment lines by using the `#` character, e.g.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYY

#[qa]
#aws_access_key_id = AAAAAAAAA
#aws_secret_access_key = BBBBBB
```